# In magento 2 need to split the shipment based on product custom column value

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5

In magento 2.4.5 we need to split the shipment based on product custom column value using observer on saving time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to send the shipment  mail  on seller wise product one shipment have multiple seller

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this code . I hope you will get an idea

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SplitShipment implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $shipmentItemFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\ItemFactory $shipmentItemFactory
    ) {
        $this->shipmentItemFactory = $shipmentItemFactory;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            $product = $item->getProduct();
            $customColumnValue = $product->getData('custom_column_name');

            if ($customColumnValue == 'some_condition') {
                $shipmentItem = $this->shipmentItemFactory->create([
                    'data' => [
                        'order_item_id' => $item->getId(),
                        'qty' => $item->getQtyOrdered(),
                        'weight' => $item->getWeight(),
                        // set other properties as needed
                    ]
                ]);

                $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
            }
        }

        $shipment->register();
        $shipment->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: in this $shipment is not declared and another we need to group product custom value and create shipment